# Kubernetes Deployment: get number of pods that are AVAILABLE AND UP-TO-DATE

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Suppose that:

- you have a deployment with 1 replicas (for simplicity)
- you deploy a new version and the deployment fails, because the image doesn't work..

The output of `kubectl get` after some time is this:

```
NAME             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
web-deployment   1/1     1            1           10d
```

If I see something like that I expect that everything is fine... `1/1` and 1 up-to-date. However that's not true!

There is 1 pod `UP-TO-DATE` [but not running] and 1 pod `READY` [but not up-to-date]... they are different pods!

This is really confusing and misleading... Is there any way to see the number of pods that are `AVAILABLE` **AND** `UP-TO-DATE` (at the same time)?

Comment: You typically need custom tooling to get a good control on what you are asking. It's a good question and I have been working with such kind of problems. You can try to track the ReplicaSets for more details, e.g. start with `kubectl get rs`

Comment: Agreed with @Jonas that it's simple to with `kubectl get rs` to get info about different ReplicaSets. Since every ReplicaSet has a hash that automatically added to the name during deployment, you can simple check info only for needed ReplicaSet. More information can be found from this example on [Kubernetes site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment)

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, `kubectl get rs` is a good solution to start.

To show it I used an example of the deployment from [kubernetes site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment).

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

After creating the Deployment, we can check the information about the ReplicaSet:

```
kubectl get rs -l app=nginx
NAME                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5   3         3         3       7m
```

Then update the Deployment with any changes and deploy it.
We can observe rollout process of a new Deployment using the `--watch` flag:

```
kubectl get rs -l app=nginx --watch
NAME                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5   3         3         3       8m
nginx-deployment-559d658b74   1         0         0       0s
nginx-deployment-559d658b74   1         0         0       0s
nginx-deployment-559d658b74   1         1         0       0s
nginx-deployment-559d658b74   1         1         1       9s
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5   2         3         3       8m
nginx-deployment-559d658b74   2         1         1       9s
nginx-deployment-559d658b74   2         1         1       9s
nginx-deployment-559d658b74   2         2         1       9s
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5   2         3         3       8m
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5   2         2         2       8m
nginx-deployment-559d658b74   2         2         2       18s
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5   1         2         2       8m
nginx-deployment-559d658b74   3         2         2       18s
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5   1         2         2       8m
nginx-deployment-559d658b74   3         2         2       18s
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5   1         1         1       8m
nginx-deployment-559d658b74   3         3         2       18s
nginx-deployment-559d658b74   3         3         3       20s
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5   0         1         1       8m
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5   0         1         1       8m
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5   0         0         0       8m
```

This is useful to see where we are now - the number of pods for every ReplicaSet during the deployment.

Information about the ReplicaSet:

```
kubectl get rs -l app=nginx
NAME                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
nginx-deployment-559d658b74   3         3         3       36s
nginx-deployment-66b6c48dd5   0         0         0       9m
```

We can also check the pods:

```
kubectl get pods --show-labels
NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   LABELS
nginx-deployment-559d658b74-4gt24                1/1     Running   0          44s   app=nginx,pod-template-hash=559d658b74
nginx-deployment-559d658b74-tzv94                1/1     Running   0          35s   app=nginx,pod-template-hash=559d658b74
nginx-deployment-559d658b74-w2svm                1/1     Running   0          27s   app=nginx,pod-template-hash=559d658b74
```

They have the `pod-template-hash=559d658b74` label. This hash is automatically appended to the ReplicaSet name, pod name, and helps to distinguish different deployments.

More information on the deployment process is available on [the official site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).